# WIFI_P2P_DISCOVERY_CHANGED_ACTION intent action is never sent

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct

I'm doing an application based on wifi direct. According with the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#WIFI_P2P_DISCOVERY_CHANGED_ACTION) I was expecting to receive the WIFI_P2P_DISCOVERY_CHANGED_ACTION intent action when I call discoverPeers(), but for some reason this intent is never sent to my broadcast receiver. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: I've built the WiFi direct demo, and with what seems like all WiFi direct applications, it doesn't work well. After one or two connections it will stop working. I think the software stack for WiFi direct in android is broken.

Comment: After some days of attempts I am starting to think the same thing...

Comment: I opened a bug thread on AOSP's page: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42645 Star or comment on it to bring attention to it.